# PHP ->exec() Successful, but nothing is stored in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a MySQL query that not only works fine from PhpMyAdmin, but also seems to be running successfully from PHP.

My SQL statement is basically this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO store_to_status 
    (
        XYZ_id, ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO
    ) 
    (
        SELECT XYZ_id, ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO
            FROM status_table WHERE obj_type = $obj_type
    )";
$db->exec($query);
```

When I try to run this statement, no records are inserted into the table.

BUT--when I `echo` the exec(), it echo's the number of rows that are supposed to be inserted. Even more interestingly, the ID column (which is set to auto-increment) thinks the insert was successful (meaning, if I try to insert a test record after this statement, and run the page a couple of times, there is a gap of 7 numbers between each test-record ID)!

Comment: Is this sql server or mysql? You have tagged both.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code at all (i.e. look at error messages)?

Comment: @MikeBrant-yep, no errors coming up :(

Comment: @SeanLange-Oops, sorry, you're right. Removed sql-server

Comment: is $obj_type a number?

Comment: Sounds like a commit is missing, but thats rather untypical for mysql.

Comment: Checked that the `select` actually returns anything? Failure to find anything in the select wouldn't make the insert be counted as a failure. an empty result set is still a valid result set.

Comment: @MarcB-I think it is returning something, because `echo` echo's the number of rows it's supposed to be copying

Comment: @eckes-Can you please explain? I don't understand...

Comment: what does `select max(XYZ_id) from store_to_status` return? do you see the ID that you are expecting after the auto-increment or still the ID of an old record?

Answer (score 0):

That `INSERT` is successful, even when not inserting any values. Make sure your `SELECT` actually returns rows.

Comment: I think it is returning something, because echo echo's the number of rows it's supposed to be copying...

Comment: Can you verify by actually executing the select statement in your php?

Comment: -Yes, I have verified it. Perhaps in the context of the overall query it isn't working, but when taken in isolation, it most definitely does work

Comment: Haven't tried this, but usually there is no () around your select statement